# Problem in solving a simple Laplace equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve the following Laplace PDE in MMA:

$$\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2}=0$$

subject to the boundary conditions:
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}|_{z=0}=0,$$

and, at $z=1$ $$-\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}+A=BT,$$

This is my code:

```
DSolve[{D[T[x, z], {x, 2}] + D[T[x, z], {z, 2}] == 0, 
(D[T[x, z], z] /. {z -> 0}) == 0, 
-(D[T[x, z], z] /. {z -> 1}) + A == B T[x, 1]}, T[x, z], {x, z}]
```

But it just repeats my equation.

Thank you for kindly help in advance!

Comment: Can you check to make sure that you don't have any definitions for the symbols you use in your equations?

Comment: The syntax in `D[T[x, 0],z]`is not correct: you should evaluate in $z=0$ _after_ taking the derivative. This yields `0==0` and so your error. Apart from this, are you sure about you boundary/initial conditions? Seems to me you are missing some.

Comment: Hi, @anderstood, thanks. Please check my modified post. It seems that MMA has done nothing...

Comment: What if you solve only the pde (`DSolve[{D[T[x, z], {x, 2}] + D[T[x, z], {z, 2}] == 0}, T[x, z], {x, z}]`) and add the boundary conditions afterwards to identify the constants?

Comment: Thanks, @anderstood. Your method looks feasible. But I have not realized it by now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another problem easy to do by separation of variables.  However, BC's on x are definitely required to solve the problem.  The assumption of `exp[i a x]` requires BC's that make sinusoidal solutions in x.

```
pde = D[T[x, z], x, x] + D[T[x, z], z, z] == 0;
```

With the BC's you give I add 2 more for x.  The ones I chose will give sinusoidal solutions.  You, of course can choose others

```
bc1 = T[0, z] == 0;
bc2 = T[1, z] == 0;
bc3 = (D[T[x, z], z] /. z -> 0) == 0;
bc4 = (D[T[x, z], z] /. z -> 1) == A - B T[x, 1];
```

Separate T in the form

```
T[x_, z_] = X[x] Z[z];

pde/T[x, z] // Apart

(* D[X[x],x,x]/X[x]+D[Z[z],z,z]/Z[z]==0 *)
```

One terms is dependent on x, the other z, so each must be equal to a constant.

```
xeq = D[X[x], x, x]/X[x] == -alpha^2

 X[x_] = (X[x] /. DSolve[xeq, X[x], x][[1]]) /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2};

zeq = D[Z[z], z, z]/Z[z] == alpha^2

Z[z_] = (Z[z] /. DSolve[zeq, Z[z], z][[1]]) /. {C[1] -> c3,  C[2] -> c4}

(* c3 E^(alpha z)+c4 E^(-alpha z) *)
```

From the z BC's, it is obvious we want hyberbolics rather than exponentials.

```
(Z[z] // ExpToTrig) // Collect[#, {Sinh[alpha z], Cosh[alpha z]}] &

(* (c3-c4) Sinh[alpha z]+(c3+c4) Cosh[alpha z] *)

Z[z_] = % /. {c3 - c4 -> c3, c3 + c4 -> c4};
(* c3 Sinh[alpha z] + c4 Cosh[alpha z] *)
```

Apply the BC's

bc1

```
(* c1 (c3 Sinh[\[Alpha] z] + c4 Cosh[\[Alpha] z]) == 0 *)
```

From which

```
c1 = 0

T[x, z]
(* c2 Sin[alpha x] (c3 Sinh[alpha z] + c4 Cosh[alpha z])*)
```

Combine constants

```
c2 = 1;

bc2

(* Sin[alpha] (c3 Sinh[alpha z] + c4 Cosh[alpha z]) == 0 *)
```

From which

```
alpha = n Pi
```

with `n` required to be

```
$Assumptions = n \[Element] Integers && n > 0;

bc3
(* Pi c3 n Sin[Pi n x]==0 *)
```

From which

```
c3 = 0;

bc4 // Simplify
(* c4 Sin[Pi n x] (B Cosh[Pi n]+Pi n Sinh[Pi n])==A *)
```

Use orthogonality to solve for c4

```
Integrate[%[[1]] Sin[n Pi x], {x, 0, 1}] ==  Integrate[%[[2]] Sin[n Pi x], {x, 0, 1}];

c4 = c4 /. Solve[%, c4][[1]]

T[x, z]

(*-((2 A ((-1)^n - 1) Sin[Pi n x] Cosh[Pi n z])/(Pi n (B Cosh[Pi n] + Pi n Sinh[Pi n]))) *)
```

The actual T will be an infinite series in n, but obviously from the form of the solution, the even n terms are 0.  In order to not compute the 0 terms we can do the following:

```
Tn[x_, z_] = (T[x, z] /. n -> 2 m - 1) /. m -> n // Simplify

(*(4 A Sin[Pi (2 n-1) x] Cosh[Pi (2 n-1) z])/(Pi (2 n-1) (B Cosh[Pi-2 Pi n]+Pi (2 n-1) Sinh[Pi (2 n-1)]))*)
```

The general solution is the above summed from n = 1 to infinity.
To make a plot:

```
tn = Function[n, #] &@Tn[x, z];
```

Assign A and B some values.

```
A = 1;
B = 2;

Tterms[k_] := Compile[{x, z}, #] &@Total@tn@Range[k]

T = Tterms[50];

Plot3D[T[x, z], {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "T"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is a problem about your solution, it is that DSolve cannot handle it and, therefore, returns you the input unevaluated, as a signal. So, what you can do, if you do not want to solve it analytically (seems a simple task, does not it?) you might want to solve it numerically, that is, using NDSolve. This, of course, will reguire from you to somehow fix the values of A and B, otherwise, however, it can be solved. Try this:

```
   A = 1;
B = 2;

<< NDSolve`FEM`
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]];
nv1 = NeumannValue[A - B*T[x, z], z == 1];
nv2 = NeumannValue[0, z == 0];
dc = DirichletCondition[T[x, z] == 1, x == 0];
sl = NDSolve[{D[T[x, z], {x, 2}] + D[T[x, z], {z, 2}] == nv1 + nv2, 
   dc}, T[x, z], {x, z} \[Element] mesh]

(*  {{T[x, z] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}, <>][x, z]}}  *)
```

To have a look at the solution evaluate this:

```
Plot3D[T[x, z] /. sl[[1, 1]], {x, z} \[Element] mesh, 
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

which should look as follows:

[image]

Take into account that I added a Dirichlet condition

```
 dc = DirichletCondition[T[x, z] == 1, x == 0];
```

otherwise there is nothing to look at in the solution, as it was.

Have fun!

Comment: @ Alexei Boulbitch, Thank you. But I have some troubles in debugging your code. I am using MMA 9. First, what is the meaning of `<<` before your `NDSolve`FEM``. I guess you want to use `Needs`? Second, when I run it, MMA gives _NDSolve::dvnoarg: "The function T[x,z] appears with no arguments. "_. In addition, I think the original two boundary condition are sufficient to solve for the function T(x,z) even analytically. For example, assuming $T(x,z)=\theta(z)\exp[i\alpha x]$, we can obtain $T(x,z)=\frac{A \cosh \alpha z}{B\cosh \alpha + \alpha \sinh \alpha}$.

Comment: @ lxy Welcome. To address your questions. 1. `<< NDSolve`FEM`  is the short form of `Needs... `. You may use the latter instead. 2. I am not quite sure, if Mma 9 already has the NDSolve`FEM` package. If not (which is possible), it is the reason for the strange warnings like "The function T[x,z] appears with no arguments". 3. Indeed the original boundary conditions enable one to solve the equation. The solution, however, was a constant. That's why I added something to see that there is at least some variation, and in this way to check that there is, indeed, a solution.

Comment: @ Alexei Boulbitch, Thanks, I confirmed that MMA9 does not have `FEM` package, and it can run on version 10 :)